# How can I make a rubber cover for my hammer?

Tags: tools, product-recommendation

I have a hammer (wooden handle with steel head) that I love (kind of an heirloom) and I like using it for lots of things. Its great for most jobs, but there are some things where I don't want the steel hammer head to make contact with what I am hammering. Instead of going out and buying a separate rubber hammer, I want to create a DIY hammer accessory whereby I slide on a rubber sleeve or cover on to the head. This way, whenever I encounter the kind of tasks that require a rubber hammering end, I can just put the rubber cover on and hammer away.

The trouble is, I'm skeptical as to how feasible this idea is. I haven't seen many rubber products out there that are close to being the right dimensions to fit snugly on my hammer. For example, I found some hammer covers on amazon but they are actually whole rubber head replacements and they interface with a screw threading. I just want a slide on cover.

Then I thought, maybe I can call up a rubber manufacturer and say: "hey uh, want to help a brother out?" but I think that's most likely going to be a difficult course of action because I don't know any one who works in that industry and I have a sinking feeling if I want a custom mold they will need a minimum order (like 1000 pcs or something).

Here is a visual representation of what I'm after:

[image]

**EDIT** My hammer is pretty much like this picture, wooden handle and everything. One difference is that my hammer head is actually a square, 1.25"x1.25" Depth doesn't matter so much, but I'd want the rubber cove to probably be around the .25-.5" range. Sorry for not providing this information earlier; just realized how important it was :(

**Question:** Is there an economical way I can tackle my thus far hypothetical DIY rubber hammer cover project? Or alternatively, is there a product out there somewhere that could work for my task?

**Further Clarifications:**

- rubber cover must slide on snuggly to my hammer
- ideally, for DIY approach, I'd like it to fit perfectly (tailor made feel) if that's possible
- budget is $20
- must work with my heirloom hammer (no buying other rubber hammers as replacement)

Comment: The really only feasible answer here is to buy appropriately sized rubber chair leg caps in the appropriate size.  Sure they aren’t perfectly flat, but it’s simple and cheap.

Comment: I would look for rubber crutch tips - might be about the right size.

Comment: Carving down a vibration pad or other solid rubber block would probably work.

Comment: You would possibly get a better focused answer if you were to take a digital caliper and measure the diameter and depth of the hammer head. Then add that information to your question.

Comment: i push a plastic bottle cap (like from juice or soda) onto mine when i don't want to scratch something. If you need a real rubber mallet, you probably want a real rubber mallet (or sand mallet) do get the "thwump factor" correct.

Comment: Honestly - spend your $20 budget on a rubber hammer.   Now you have two hammers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rubber crutch tip could work. They come in different sizes. I bet you can find one that will fit nicely.

[image]

Comment: I agree, and you could use a heat gun to help "mold" the rubber, including smoothing out the ridged end of the tip.

Comment: If you're going to go this route, i would recommend a black one (butyl rubber, stinky) instead of plastic like the one shown; it will last a _lot_ longer and be _far_ less prone to splitting under force. more bouncy too.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother. Nothing pliable enough to stretch over and stay on the hammer head is going to survive being used AS a hammer for more than a few whacks. That's especially problematic for a "square" headed hammer, i.e. corners are just going to poke through in no time. For the few times per year I need a rubber hammer, I just went out to the cheap Chinese junk tool store (named Harbor Freight around here) and bought one for something like $2. Either that or just get a square rubber floor protector (for furniture legs) and put it on whatever *needs* hammering, not on the hammer itself.

Idea 3; you can get a liquid rubbery plastic goop that you use to coat tool *handles* and coat the head of the hammer every time you want to use it. It would likely only last a few whacks, but if that's all you need it for, peel off the goop when you are done and put it on again next time you need it.

Example: https://plastidip.com/

Comment: Agree.  The plastidip will cost more than a rubber mallet.